# Recursive function in a tree

Tags: python-3.x, function, recursion, tree, binary-tree

Assuming a tree with these nodes:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Afb9u.png)

The value in brackets are the weights of each node. We need to find the property "imbalance" of the tree in which the value of "imbalance" equals to the absolute difference between the summed weight of the left and right subtree of this node.

The imbalance of the tree would be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCUJ5.png)

So the imbalance of B and D are zero because they have no left and right child. C is 10 because its left child has the value 10. And A is 4 because the absolute summed of its left child minus the summed of right child is |12 - 8|.

How would you write a python code for this scenario? Recursive function?

Comment: Yep, recursive postorder traversal.

Comment: How would you write it?

Comment: Like a standard postorder traversal.

Comment: You should show your efforts. *"How would you write it"* is not a suitable question here. Ask about the code you have tried with and what the problem was you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

A tree is a recursive structure, so going with a recursive algorithm would indeed be better.

At each recursion, compute the sum of the recursive call on each child, and return this value. This way you can compute the summed weight of each subtree.
To have the imbalance, you'll need to construct another tree. If you have a class representation for the tree, you could do like this: At each recursion, return a pair with the summed weight and a node with the imbalance as the weight. Assign as left and right children the nodes returned by the recursive call.

Here's my quick implementation. It's a simple [post-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order,_LRN):

```py
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, weight, left, right):
        self.weight = weight
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def computeImbalance(tree):
    # Get the left value
    left = computeImbalance(tree.left) if tree.left is not None else (0, None)
    # Get the right value
    right = computeImbalance(tree.right) if tree.right is not None else (0, None)
    # Current summed weight
    sum = left[0] + right[0] + tree.weight
    imbalance = abs(left[0] - right[0])
    # Return the summed weight and the new tree
    return (sum, Tree(imbalance, left[1], right[1]))
```

Comment: an interesting question with a good answer. i believe i would have answered similarly...